# Unable to update with 'apt-get': errors

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, software-sources

Can't run `sudo apt-get update` , I get errors like:

```
E: Type '--2016-05-25' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Your source list has problem. Please update your question and add the result of this command: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list`

Answer (score 3):

The repository file needs to be fixed for `PlayOnLinux`.  Copy and paste the following lines in a terminal window to replace the existing repository file:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

*Note: If you're running Ubuntu 16.04, the PlayOnLinux repository is not Xenial ready, so the repository will be disabled.  The version of PlayOnLinux in the built-in repository is newer than in the playonlinux repository, so the file could just be deleted.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: After  running those commends in the terminal, i got this error                                                                                                                                              W: GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E0F72778C4676186

Comment: @AlbertBaloyi Updated my answer to add the key in.  Hope that helps!